# how to make a currency converter in windows store app using IValueConverter interface?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a currency converter windows store app. I have made one before but that was simple. Just take value (In Pakistani Rupees) from a TextBox and convert it into US Dollars using hard code done in another class which was using IValueConverter Interface.
Now I'm trying to make a bit more advanced version. I want that user will input the value in TextBox, then he/she will select two different currencies from two ListBoxes (From and To respectively.) and after that he/she will press the Convert button two Convert the Value From One Currency to another Currency.
The Problem here is that how should I get the value of TextBox, detect the selection of ListItems from those ListBoxes, determine the currency rate and convert?

I'm obviously Adding ScreenShots and Code. Please take a look at them and Try to Resolve my Problem.

**ScreenShot**
[image: Application Main Screen]

**XAML Code**

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar Background="#2ecc71"
                    IsSticky="True"
                    IsOpen="True"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    Height="80">
            <AppBarButton Name="App"
                          Content="App"
                          Icon="Page"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="Settings"
                          Content="Settings"
                          Icon="Setting"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>
    <Grid Background="#2ecc71">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="AppOuterContainer"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="auto"
                    Height="auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name="Heading"
                           Text="Enter a value to convert."
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Height="40"
                           FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           FontSize="32"
                           Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox Name="ValueInput"
                         Width="500"
                         Height="60"
                         FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         FontSize="26"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="From"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Height="40"
                           FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           FontSize="32"
                           Margin="10"/>
                <ListView Name="FromContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          Grid.Row="3"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Width="500"
                          Height="65"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding FlagImg}"
                                           Width="auto"
                                           Height="60"

                                           Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <StackPanel Width="auto"
                                                Height="60"
                                                Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Name="CountryName"
                                                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                                       FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                                       FontSize="28"
                                                       Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                       Foreground="White"/>
                                            <TextBlock Name="Currency"
                                                       Text="{Binding Currency}"
                                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                                       FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                                                       FontWeight="Light"
                                                       FontSize="22"
                                                       Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                       Foreground="White"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="To"
                           Grid.Row="4"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Height="40"
                           FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           FontSize="32"
                           Margin="10"/>
                <ListView Name="ToContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          Grid.Row="5"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Width="500"
                          Height="65"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding FlagImg}"
                                           Width="auto"
                                           Height="60"

                                           Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <StackPanel Width="auto"
                                                Height="60"
                                                Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Name="CountryName"
                                                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                                       FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                                       FontSize="28"
                                                       Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                       Foreground="White"/>
                                            <TextBlock Name="Currency"
                                                       Text="{Binding Currency}"
                                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                                       FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                                                       FontWeight="Light"
                                                       FontSize="22"
                                                       Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                       Foreground="White"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Button Name="ConvertBtn"
                        Content="Convert"
                        Width="200"
                        Height="60"
                        Margin="10"
                        Background="White"
                        Foreground="#2ecc71"
                        FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                        FontSize="28"
                        Grid.Row="6"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Result"
                           Text="Result"
                           FontFamily="Segoe Ui Light"
                           FontSize="28"
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="10"
                           Grid.Row="7"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs Code**

```
new Countries("Pakistan", "Pakistani Rupee", "ms-appx:///Assets/pk.png");
            new Countries("USA", "US Dollar", "ms-appx:///Assets/us.png");
            new Countries("Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Rayal", "ms-appx:///Assets/sa.png");
            new Countries("England", "Euro", "ms-appx:///Assets/gb.png");

            FromContainer.DataContext = Countries.getAllCountries();
            ToContainer.DataContext = Countries.getAllCountries();
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs under InitializeComponent();, This code block adds Countries list to ListBoxes using Binding.

**Countries.cs Code**

```
public static ObservableCollection<Countries> Country = new ObservableCollection<Countries>();

        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Currency { get; set; }
        public String FlagImg { get; set; }


        public Countries(){

        }

        public Countries(String name,String currency,String Flag)
        {
            Countries ob = new Countries();
            ob.Name = name;
            ob.Currency = currency;
            ob.FlagImg = Flag;

            Country.Add(ob);
        }

        public static  ObservableCollection<Countries> getAllCountries()
        {


             return Country;
        }
```

Observable Collection to store Countries Data (Options to choose from).

**Currency.cs Code**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            double pkr;
            double dollar = 0.0;
            if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out pkr))
            {
                dollar = pkr * 0.0099;
            }
            return dollar;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

This class implements IValueConverter interface. The code that's already in convert method is kind of static conversion method. I want to Edit this as I stated Above.

Thanks for your Time. Please let me know explicitly if there's anything wrong or missing in my Question. **Do not mark it as duplicate because there's another solution that I have already tried but that's not my requirement.**

Comment: I'm trying to involve someone who're familiar with this topic to make further test. Appreciate your patience since there might be sometime delay.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm waiting for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

> The Problem here is that how should I get the value of TextBox, detect
>   the selection of ListItems from those ListBoxes,

You can handle them in a ViewModel :

**XAML**:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InputText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding FromCountry,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string inputText;
        public string InputText
        {
            get { return inputText; }
            set
            {
                if (inputText != value)
                {
                    inputText = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InputText"));
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }



 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        MainViewModel ViewModel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new Currency_Converter.MainViewModel();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }

    }
```

> determine the currency rate and convert?

`IValueConverter` does not apply to your situation. You can make the two selected currency unified into the same currency (e.g US dollar) and store them in a local database.

By the way, I check your code and find it seems that you display currency according to your preferences. You'd better use [global-ready formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/use-global-ready-formats?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which permits you adapt your app later for additional cultures and languages in the global market.